# Install Linux using PXE

Tags: linux, boot, pxe

I'm trying to install Linux using PXE Boot. I've set up the server and is running. When I try to get the `pxelinux.0` file using tftp it succeeds to get the file.

You can see in this video what is happening: In [this YouTube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g0abTuk7id8) you can see (in a verry brief split second) that it boots from the network and gets the pxelinux.0 file:

[image: gets the file]

When it tries to boot the system it gives the message that **Succeed to download NBP file**. At 0:12 you can see that it boots into the currently installed operating system

It works when I use it on another Virtual machine and the machine I'm trying to install it on supports PXE boot, so that can't be the issue. I have no idea where to look.

Comment: That looks like UEFI. It won’t boot `pxelinux.0`, which is for BIOS only.

Comment: Thanks @DanielB Your comment help me solve a problem I had for 3 days... I Googled UEFI PXE boot and stumbled uppon this article from Ubuntu: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UEFI/PXE-netboot-install. Got it up and running in couple of minutes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution in this case is as follows. Don't use `pxelinux.0` if you're working with UEFI instead of BIOS.

I reinstalled my PXE Server and used this guide: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UEFI/PXE-netboot-install on the Ubuntu Wiki. It works like a charm!

So if you use bios you can use most guides you can find online (that's why i F*ed up) but if you use UEFI, you have to look a bit further.

(Thanks to [Daniel B](https://superuser.com/users/219095/daniel-b))